# Can not access DOM elements on a jquery dialog box 

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Requirement: I am using Jquery portlet plugin for my project. On clicking an expand button on a portlet div, a modal dialog box will appear with the contents of the portlet div.

Here is my code:

```
function expand()
{
    var placeHolderDiv = $("#" + expandPlaceHolderDiv)
    var content = $(portletDiv).clone(true);  //  portletDiv is a jquery object .
    $(content).appendTo(placeHolderDiv); 
    openDialog(expandPlaceHolderDiv);
}
```

Now if I am trying to do some operation in actual portlet div it's all working fine.

For example: I have a text box on the div and I am displaying the value of the text box on a click event of a button.

But once the dialog box appears, I am unable to do any DOM manipulation. But the click event is working.